# Preg Match checking in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I have pattern like this 'D34566'. how i can check this pattern contains in the given string.

```
String =  D34566-Test Case.
Pattern = D followed by 5 digits.
```

i.e A word starting with D and followed by 5 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("/^D\d{5}/", $string)
```

Comment: Can i check D or A is it possible?

Comment: `preg_match("/^[DA]\d{5}/", $string)`, that would check if it starts with D or A

Comment: This will match `D123456789`.

Comment: hmm, right, will need to add the non number after \d{5}? `preg_match("/^[DA]\d{5}\D/", $string)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following pattern that checks the word you want to find anywhere in string:

```
if (preg_match('/\bD\d{5}\b/', $string)) {
    // OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Like this:**

```
preg_match('/^(D\d{5})/', String);
```

Comment: This will match `D123456789`.